# How to print on the screen having an API request?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, gson, okhttp

I have been several tutorials to create an API request and printing on the screen, and all the tutorials I did have some deprecated function that now I can't use.

What I have? I have the API request as you can see in the code, but now I need to print on the screen. And I don't know how to do it

PS: I use `okhttp` and the `gson` library

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fetchJson()
    }

    fun fetchJson() {
        val url = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/youtube/home_feed"
        var request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        var client = OkHttpClient()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                val body = response.body()?.string()
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()

                val homeFeed = gson.fromJson(body, HomeFeed::class.java)
                println(homeFeed.videos)
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed on execute")
            }
        })

    }

}

class HomeFeed(val videos: List<Video>)

class Video(val id: Int, val name:String, val link: String, val imageUrl: String, numberOfViews: String, val channel: Channel)

class Channel(val name: String, val profileImageUrl: String)
```

Answer (score 2):

To simply print your debug logs to the `Logcat` just use:

```
Log.d("TAG", "videos: ${homeFeed.videos}")
```

Note: to print your list of videos in a human readable way you must make your `Video` and `Channel` classes as data classes (this automatically overrides their `toString()` functions):

```
data class Video(val id: Int, val name:String, val link: String, val imageUrl: String, numberOfViews: String, val channel: Channel)
data class Channel(val name: String, val profileImageUrl: String)
```

Also, as a long term solution, there is a better way to do HTTP logging (for debugging purposes) when using `okhttp` and it relies on using [HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/logging-interceptor/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.html).

So, to print all your HTTP requests and responses with error codes, simply add a `httpLoggingInterceptor` to your client like this:

```
val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    }
val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
    .build()
```

You can read more about OkHttp interceptors [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/#application-interceptors).

Answer (score 0):

`print()`/`println()` isn't working in Android.

You have two options:

1. Add TextView to your activity and show text there

   ```
   textView.text = homeFeed.videos
   ```

   or

   ```
   textView.text = "Failed on execute"
   ```
2. Use [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat), `Log.d()` or similar method from `Log` class.

Comment: I don't know how to use the first one.